# Skype on Ubuntu: how to disable "Send message" on Enter and enable "New line" on Enter

Tags: ubuntu, skype, skype-for-linux

How to disable "Send message" on Enter and enable "New line" on Enter?
Is there an option on Ubuntu version of Skype?
I cannot find it

Answer (score 1):

Hold shift when clicking enter.

And skype for linux is seriously lackluster. It may be easier to use the skype web interface. That one has a checkbox somewhere for it, even if the linux app doesn't.